# How to create ROC curve for different classifier in Weka or excel

Tags: classification, weka, naivebayes, roc, mlp

I have a array of sensitivity and specificity values for  positive class for different classifiers. I want to create one ROC curve for each classifier.

For example

```
                   Sensitivity    specificity            ROC
 NB                 0.613         0.778                  0.791
 LR                 0.865         0.842                  0.88
 MLP                0.976         0.903                  0.959
```

Those are not real value I created those value for demonstration purpose. I mention here sensitivity and specificity because ROC is the ratio of True positive and False positive rate.

I want a plot like that

[image]

I also go through the [Weka Tutorial 30: Multiple ROC Curves (Model Evaluation)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZHw3gGe7DA). The knowledge flow diagram he was talking about had two drawback

```
1. If I have a training and test dataset and I want to see the ROC of test dataset that was not defined there.

2. If I am using 5 fold cross validation on training set how could I represent that, that was also not defined.
```

I tried to make a knowledge flow environment by myself but I did not get the option on arff loader "the load model".

Comment: What are your x and y axis?

Comment: Besides, "sensitivity and specificity values for positive class" makes no sense at all to me. Can you rephrase this part?

Comment: X axis False positive rate Y True positive rate. My question is about knowledge flow diagram,how to implement and make it work. Do you have any idea?